# How to solve $2x- x^2 - \sin x +1 =0$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, trigonometry

I came across this number in a German Math Paper. After diffentiating the question i reached $2x- x^2 - \sin x +1 =0$ and this is where i am stuck right now as i cant figure out the next step.

Comment: this is a transcendental equation, as far as I know it can't be solved exactly, only numerically

Comment: "After differentiating the question..." Where is the question?

Comment: Such equations can only be solved numerically , unless you can guess one or more solutions and show that there are no more.

Comment: Something related to $-\frac13 x^3+x^2+x+\cos x + C$ I bet

Comment: You can differentiate an expression, not an equation. E.g In $cosx=x$, after differentiating gives $sinx=1$, which gives $x=π/2$ (not a solution).

Comment: **Hint:** You want to solve $2-(1-x)^2=\sin x$

Comment: @Shashwat1337 "You can differentiate an expression, not an equation." Not true. you can put *any operation* to both sides of the equation.  How else do you transform an equation?

Comment: I meant an equation, not an identity. Specifically, the 'equation' you described is a one valid for all $x$. I am talking about equations having particular roots. E.g : $x^2+1 =3$.

Comment: x=-0.414 can be close to the solution.

Comment: @Shashwat1337 "I am talking about equations having particular roots. E.g : x2+1=3. "... Well then you are taking not about functions. $x$ not being a variable but a parameter. And, sorry, I don't have any references about the difference, just my own 2cents.

Comment: @Shashwat1337 ". I am talking about equations having particular roots. " ... so you're talking about roots,numbers that resolve the equation, not about the equation itself.  That's a big difference,.

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$f'(x)=-2(x-1)-\cos x \implies f''(x)=\sin x-2 <0$$

with $f'(0)=2>0$, $f'(2)<0$ therefore by IVT $f'(x)$ has exactly one root in the interval $[0,2]$ and $f(x)$ has a maximum in that interval and exactly $2$ roots which can be only found numerically.